tqdm to track progress on chain of operations on a pandas dataframe
Is there a way to use tqdm to track progress on a long chain of processes applied to a pandas DataFrame? Here's what my code looks like:
dataframe = (
  dataframe
    .drop_duplicates()
    .dropna()
    .groupby('date')
    .agg(items=('items','sum'))
    .sort_values(['date','items'])
)

I'm already using tqdm to track progress while loading the data from a few large CSV files. I was wondering if there's a way to do that on the pandas processes too, as they also take a while.
After looking around I couldn't find any threads on this topic and I wasn't able to make much progress (no pun intended) reading tqdm's documentation. I can't use .progress_apply because of the call to .drop_duplicates which can't be applied to individual rows. Any suggestions?

What will the progress unit be?
